# Excel Vba Print Userform and save Userform as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, directory, userform

I have a project that requires user entry form to be printed, renamed and saved to a specific folder

I've gone through numerous subjects relating to .printform command on this platform and usually the solutions requires to PrintScreen, save as bitmap, paste to new workbook and use Activesheet.ExportAsFixedFormat to set as pdf......

but then
My userforms width is 603,
My userforms height is 875,
The userform requires a vertical scrollbar to view all details
So "SnapScreen" wouldn't go a long way

The current code i have uses .printform command
and asks me to choose the printer i want to print to
and if the selected printer isn't active on my computer, it aborts command

Below is the code

```
Option Explicit
Private Const HWND_BROADCAST As Long = &HFFFF&
Private Const WM_WININICHANGE As Long = &H1A
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
(ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendNotifyMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendNotifyMessageA" ( _
  ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
  ByVal Msg As Long, _
  ByVal wParam As Long, _
  lParam As Any) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetDefaultPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "SetDefaultPrinterA" ( _
  ByVal pszPrinter As String) As Long
 
Public Sub ChangePrinter(NewPrinter As String)
 
  SetDefaultPrinter NewPrinter
  Call SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, _
    WM_WININICHANGE, _
    0, ByVal "windows")
 
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Print_Click()

Dim Msg As String
    Dim ireply As Integer


        ireply = MsgBox("Select Active-Printer", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel)
        Select Case ireply
            Case vbOK
                GoTo line123456
            Case vbCancel
                  Exit Sub
          End Select
          
line123456:
Dim dir as string
Dim OldPrinter As String
  Dim NewPrinter As String
  OldPrinter = Left(Application.ActivePrinter, InStrRev(Application.ActivePrinter, "on ") - 2)
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
  NewPrinter = Left(Application.ActivePrinter, InStrRev(Application.ActivePrinter, "on ") - 2)
''folderpath (created pdf to be renamed based on textbox value)
'dir =  "C:\Users\user\Documents\Almadina Related\NHIS RELATED" & Me.txt_pNameDefaultclaimsForm.Value & ".pdf"

ChangePrinter NewPrinter
  
  On Error GoTo Endproc

Me.PrintForm

GoTo SkipExit

Endproc:
MsgBox "Sorry, print command aborted - a default printer is not selected"
Unload Me
Exit Sub

SkipExit:

  ChangePrinter OldPrinter
  
End Sub
```

Kindly Help.
is it possible to print, rename and save USERFORM to a specific folder as pdf

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm not well-knowing with vba. So practically 90% of the code was derived from related problems. my purpose yeah?, is to give the user the ability to print userform to an active printer and save the userform as pdf to a folder, without the user needing to select a file destination but only picking the desired printer. May i reword the above - when user clicks on print, user gets a dialoguebox to select an active printer, if user chooses to print to a pdf printer, then the pdf File generated, will be saved to a folder path with a textbox value as pdf Filename

Comment: If user chooses a direct printer, pdf should still be generated as well and saved with textbox value as pdf Filename

Comment: Thank you for your reply, apologies If I haven't made my aim/purpose clear enough to understand... this userform were the user gets to save and print...is not designed on excel spreadsheet ... it is designed in VBA userforms, so the userform print command, captures the userform!.... every detail and every entry would be made by user on vba userforms, that's what I'm working with

Comment: I was advised to use spreadsheets rather than userforms to design a data entry form. Because obviously, it seems like userforms aren't meant to be saved and printed in the manner I'm requesting... thing is, I have over 18 forms already built on vba userforms which I've inserted buttons that are already interactive and everything works fine... the problem now is how to get to print and back up the entry made

Comment: Thanks again, Absolutely!! a second button for pdf would have been perfect ! I tried stackoverflow.com/a/53366197/10802527 solution... this uses print screen to take a snapshot of the userform and paste it to a new workbook and save as pdf... yes that would have been perfect but my form has a vertical scrollbar...taking a snapshot would capture only half the information on my userform, I think I mentioned this in my post

Comment: thanks for digging up stuffs, the code hinted is: form1.height = form1.scrollheight ((to be done Before printing)),i attempted this and im not sure the code would run when print doesn't happen directly from the userform, if i'm not mistaking, you're suggesting i still use screen printing to solve this problem yeah? as to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366197/10802527