# Excel VBA - How to pull data from a sheet and display in a User Form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a sheet that has an option to open a user form - in this form I want to be able to select a User ID (those ID's are displayed in Column A of Sheet 1) I want it to then populate the rest of the form using the data from the row that corresponds to the User ID selected.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YICWq.png)

I then want the option to be able to print the form into a PDF?
[Example of Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E51ZU.png)

The idea is we have a skills matrix which details an engineers skillset, we want to be able to find a single engineer and print there skills into a form?

I have found a way to take data entered into a VBA form and put it into a sheet, but not the other way around. Not sure if its possible?

I have already for the User ID combo box to refernece the values in column A but need help on an example code to be able to pull data based on the value selected in Combo Box 1 using the data from Sheet 1.

I tried the following code as a starter but it doesn't function:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim searchValue As String
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim resultRow As Long

' Get the value of the ComboBox
searchValue = ComboBox1.Value

' Set the search range to Column A of Sheet1
Set searchRange = Sheets("Master Skills Matrix").Range("A:A")

' Find the first instance of the search value in the search range
resultRow = CInt(Application.Match(searchValue, searchRange, 0))

' If the search value is found, display the contents of that row in TextBox5
If Not IsError(resultRow) Then
    TextBox5.Value = Sheets("Master Skills Matrix").Cells(resultRow, 1).EntireRow.Value
Else
    TextBox5.Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you worked out how you are going to print the form to pdf ?

Comment: @CDP1802 - I'm thinking this thread may help me with the "Print to PDF" ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364850/excel-vba-userform-printscreen-save-as-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the columns into a string

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As String, searchRange As Range
    Dim resultRow As Long, c As Long, s As String
       
    ' Get the value of the ComboBox
    searchValue = ComboBox1.Value
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Master Skills Matrix")
    With ws
    
        ' Set the search range to Column A of Sheet1
        Set searchRange = .Range("A:A")
        
        ' Find the first instance of the search value in the search range
        resultRow = CInt(Application.Match(searchValue, searchRange, 0))
        
        ' If the search value is found, display the contents of that row in TextBox5
        If Not IsError(resultRow) Then
            For c = 6 To 10 ' Col F to J
                s = s & .Cells(3, c) & " : " & .Cells(resultRow, c) & vbCrLf
            Next
            TextBox5.Value = s
        Else
            TextBox5.Value = ""
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub
```